# Django traceback on queries

Tags: sql, django, performance, django-models, backtrace

I want a traceback from every query executed during a request, so I can find where they're coming from and reduce the count/complexity.

I'm using [this](https://gist.github.com/j4mie/956843) excellent snippet of middleware to list and time queries, but I don't know where in the they're coming from.

I've poked around in [django/db/models/sql/compiler.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.7c1/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py) but apparent form getting a local version of django and editing that code I can't see how to latch on to queries. Is there a signal I can use? it seems like there [isn't a signal on every query](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5415).

Is it possible to specify the default `Manager`?

(I know about django-toolbar, I'm hoping there's a solution without using it.)

Comment: What do you mean where they are coming from? The request or the code base?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An ugly but effective solution (eg. it prints the trace on all queries and only requires one edit) is to add the following to the bottom of `settings.py`:

```
import django.db.backends.utils as bakutils
import traceback

bakutils.CursorDebugWrapper_orig = bakutils.CursorWrapper

def print_stack_in_project():
    stack = traceback.extract_stack()
    for path, lineno, func, line in stack:
        if 'lib/python' in path or 'settings.py' in path:
            continue
        print 'File "%s", line %d, in %s' % (path, lineno, func)
        print '  %s' % line

class CursorDebugWrapperLoud(bakutils.CursorDebugWrapper_orig):
    def execute(self, sql, params=None):
        try:
            return super(CursorDebugWrapperLoud, self).execute(sql, params)
        finally:
            print_stack_in_project()
            print sql
            print '\n\n\n'

    def executemany(self, sql, param_list):
        try:
            return super(CursorDebugWrapperLoud, self).executemany(sql, param_list)
        finally:
            print_stack_in_project()
            print sql
            print '\n\n\n'

bakutils.CursorDebugWrapper = CursorDebugWrapperLoud
```

Still not sure if there is a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `bakutils.CursorDebugWrapper_orig = bakutils.CursorDebugWrapper`?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This gist contains version for Python 3 https://gist.github.com/Sinkler/a3108648b3aa4f867681ec11ac1b4529

Answer (score 1):

Django debug toolbar will tell you what you want with spectacular awesomeness.